# Traversing Array of Hashes in perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have a structure as below:

```
my $var1 = [{a=>"B", c=>"D"}, {E=>"F", G=>"H"}];
```

Now I want to traverse the first hash and the elements in it.. How can I do it?

When I do a dumper of `$var1` it gives me `Array` and when on `@var1` it says a hash.

Comment: I like this question, this is how I began too :D

Answer (score 4):

You iterate over the array as you would with any other array, and you'll get hash references. Then iterate over the keys of each hash as you would with a plain hash reference.

Something like:

```
foreach my $hash (@{$var1}) {
  foreach my $key (keys %{$hash}) {
    print $key, " -> ", $hash->{$key}, "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I need to get to the first element of this structure.. it would be : @$var1[0]->{'a'} .Am I correct?

Comment: Yes it worked.. Thanks guys.. now I understood the concept... :)

Comment: @user2013387 When `$arrayref` is a reference to an array, you access one element like `$arrayref->[0]` (notice the unchanged sigil, and the arrow). Alternative: `$$arrayref[0]`. Similar, we can access elements in hashrefs like `$hashref->{a}` (or `$$hashref{a}`). If the first element in an arrayref is a hashref, we can access one member like `$var->[0]->{a}`. Arrows between *subscripts* can be elided ⇒ `$var->[0]{a}` (or `$$var[0]{a}`). Do not use the `@` or `%` sigils when subscripting, these tell Perl that you are talking about multiple values, or a *slice*.

Comment: thanks amon, I have bookmarked this link :D it is great when sm1 can make corrections to the stuff that you already know, really adds to the knowledge :D

Comment: I wonder how this will be when data defined as `my @var1 = ({a=>"B", c=> "D"}, {E=>"F", G=>"H"});`.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you're going to trip Perl's strict mode with your variable declaration that includes barewords.

With that in mind, complete annotated example given below.

```
use strict;

my $test = [{'a'=>'B','c'=>'D'},{'E'=>'F','G'=>'H'}];

# Note the @{ $test }
# This says "treat this scalar reference as a list".
foreach my $elem ( @{ $test } ){
    # At this point $elem is a scalar reference to one of the anonymous
    # hashes
    #
    # Same trick, except this time, we're asking Perl
    # to treat the $elem reference as a reference to hash
    #
    # Hence, we can just call keys on it and iterate
    foreach my $key ( keys %{ $elem } ){
        # Finally, another bit of useful syntax for scalar references
        # The "point to" syntax automatically does the %{ } around $elem
        print "Key -> $key = Value " . $elem->{$key} . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\PERL_2~1\BASIC_~1\REVISION>type traverse.pl
my $var1=[{a=>"B", c=>"D"},{E=>"F", G=>"H"}];
foreach my $var (@{$var1}) {
  foreach my $key (keys(%$var)) {
    print $key, "=>", $var->{$key}, "\n";
  }
  print "\n";
}


C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\PERL_2~1\BASIC_~1\REVISION>traverse.pl
c=>D
a=>B

G=>H
E=>F
```

---

1. `$var1 = []` is a reference to an anonymous array
2. using the `@` sigil before it as in `$var1` gives you the access to the array it is referencing. So analogous to `foreach (@arr) {...}` you would do `foreach (@{$var1}) {...}`.
3. Now, the elements in the array that you have provided `@{$var1}` are anonymous (means not named) too, but they are anonymous hashes, so just like with the arrayref, here we do `%{$hash_reference}` to get access to the hash referenced by `$hash_reference`. Here, `$hash_reference` is `$var`.
4. After accessing the hash using `%{$var}` it becomes easy to access the keys of the hash using `keys(%$var)` or `keys(%{$var})`. Since the result returned is an array of keys therefore we can use `keys(%{$var})` inside `foreach (keys(%{$var})) {...}`.
5. We **access the scalar value** inside an anonymous hash by using a key like `$hash_reference->{$keyname}`, that's all the code did.
6. In case your array contained anonymous hashes of arrays like :
   `$var1=[ { akey=>["b", "c"], mkey=>["n", "o"]} ];`
   then, this is how you will **access the array values**:

   ```
   C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\PERL_2012\BASIC_PERL\REVISION>type traverse.pl
   my $var1=[ {akey=>["b", "c"], mkey=>["n", "o"]} ];

   foreach my $var (@{$var1}) {
     foreach my $key (keys(%$var)) {
       foreach my $elem (@{ $var->{$key} }) {
         print "$key=>$elem,";
       }
       print "\n...\n";
     }
     print "\n";
   }
   C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\PERL_2012\BASIC_PERL\REVISION>traverse.pl
   mkey=>n,mkey=>o,
   ...
   akey=>b,akey=>c,
   ...
   ```

Practice it more and regularly, it will soon become easy for you to break complex structures into such combinations. This is how I created a [large parser for another software](https://bitbucket.org/prateekmehta/blender_obj_perl_parser_bitbucket/src/2cb343b9e1a51133fa66a0e117918e4728bccab1/parser.pl?at=master), it is full of answers to your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

With one peek at amon's up-voted comment above (thanks, amon!) I was able to write this little ditty:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Given an array of hashes, print out the keys and values of each hash.

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $var1=[{A=>"B",C=>"D"},{E=>"F",G=>"H"}];
my $count = 0;

# @{$var1} is the array of hash references pointed to by $var1
foreach my $href (@{$var1})
{
    print "\nArray index ", $count++, "\n";
    print "=============\n";

    # %{$href} is the hash pointed to by $href
    foreach my $key (keys %{$href})
    {
            # $href->{$key} ( ALT: $$href{$key} ) is the value
            # corresponding to $key in the hash pointed to by
            # $href
            # print $key, " => ", $href->{$key}, "\n";
            print $key, " => ", $$href{$key}, "\n";
    }

print "\nCompare with dump():\n";
dump ($var1);

print "\nJust the first hash (index 0):\n";
# $var1->[0] ( ALT: $$var1[0] ) is the first hash reference (index 0)
# in @{$var1}
# dump ($var1->[0]);
dump ($$var1[0]);

#print "\nJust the value of key A: \"", $var1->[0]->{A}, "\"\n";
#print "\nJust the value of key A: \"", $var1->[0]{A}, "\"\n";
print "\nJust the value of key A: \"", $$var1[0]{A}, "\"\n"
```